# Can a kernel be used to define the cardinality of the union of 2 sets?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, kernel-trick

Given a space $\Omega $ with 2 sets $X\subseteq \Omega $ and $Y\subseteq \Omega $, how can I define a kernel $k(X,Y)=|X\cup Y|$?

I know that I can define a kernel $k_1(X,Y)=|X\cap Y|$ by setting $k_1(X,Y)=\langle\Phi_1(X),\Phi_1(Y)\rangle$ with $\Phi_1(X)$ as an indicator vector over the space $\mathbb{R}^{|\Omega|}$. This defines a logical AND over the domain of $\Omega$, but for the union I would need a logical OR. I have tried inverting the indicator vector s.t. it contains a $1$ whenever an element is **not** in the set, but the corresponding kernel yields $|\Omega|-|A\cup B|$ and due to the subtraction I cannot use the kernel closure properties to conclude the proof.
Is this even possible to proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by *kernel* you mean *nonnegative definite kernel*.

You can't prove that $k$ is nonnegative definite kernel since $k$ is not nonnegative definite.

Take any nonempty set $\Omega$.

Let $X_1 = \emptyset$, $X_2 = \{a\}$ for some $a \in \Omega$. Let $c_1 = 1, c_2 = -1$.

By definition, if $k$ was nonnegative definite kernel, $\sum_{i,j} c_i c_j k(X_i, X_j) \geq 0$. But

$$\sum_{i,j} c_i c_j k(X_i, X_j) = |X_1| - 2|X_1 \cup X_2| + |X_2| = 0 - 2 + 1  = -1 < 0$$

Comment: Thanks for sharing this simple example. It helped to disprove a few other examples as well.